# R session aborted when downloading files (console R crashes without error)

Tags: r, download

I am currently running some code that gets data from UN comtrade.

```
get.Comtrade <- function(url="http://comtrade.un.org/api/get?"
                         ,maxrec=1000000
                         ,type="C"
                         ,freq="A"
                         ,px="HS"
                         ,ps="now"
                         ,r
                         ,p
                         ,rg="all"
                         ,cc="TOTAL"
                         ,fmt="json"
)
{
  string<- paste(url
                 ,"max=",maxrec,"&" #maximum no. of records returned
                 ,"type=",type,"&" #type of trade (c=commodities)
                 ,"freq=",freq,"&" #frequency
                 ,"px=",px,"&" #classification
                 ,"ps=",ps,"&" #time period
                 ,"r=",r,"&" #reporting area
                 ,"p=",p,"&" #partner country
                 ,"rg=",rg,"&" #trade flow
                 ,"cc=",cc,"&" #classification code
                 ,"fmt=",fmt        #Format
                 ,sep = ""
  )
  filename <- paste0("temp/",r,p,ps,cc, ".csv") %>% str_replace_all(",", "")
  retry(download.file(string, filename, method = "wininet"), maxErrors = 5, sleep = 20)
  df <- read_csv(filename) %>%
    mutate_all(as.character, show_col_types = FALSE)
  output_df <<- df %>% bind_rows(output_df)
}


for(r in reporter_list){
  print(r)
  for(p in partner_list){
    print(p)
    rl <<- paste(r, collapse = ',')
    pl <<- paste(p, collapse = ',')
    as.list(interval_list) %>% map(~get.Comtrade(r=rl, p=pl, fmt = "csv", freq = "m", cc = "AG4", rg =regime, ps = .x))
    print("after map!")
  }
}
```

It works as follows:
Given some list of reporters (always groups of 5 or less) and group of partners (always groups of 5 or less), my code pulls the import or export data between those countries using the comtrade API for a given time interval and saves that file to a temporary directory.

My code seems to work fine for some reporter/partner pairs but when I try and run it for all reporters and one partner it seems to crash without error (R session aborted). When I run the code in command line it also crashes without error.

Please let me know if you would like to see more of my code, was not sure if I should post everything as I have a ton of functions.

Comment: It could either be a memory or API issue.

Comment: I don't think its a memory issue as these files are very small. I suppose it could be the API, but why would R close without error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue.

the command `read_csv` was reading the file in in the wrong encoding, which caused R to crash. Changing it to `read.csv` fixed the problem.

Comment: Might be good to report it as a bug (if it is) on github.